# Biblatex and chem-angew - add dots in abbreviations

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, superscripts

my professor is a bit picky about my bibliography: He needs the abbreviation of every journal with dots. Additionally he'd like the numeric citation in superscript when it is mentioned in text.

For now my bibliography simply abbreviates the Jounals without dots, neither als the citation in superscript.

Does anybody know how I can customize these two things?

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[backened = biber, style = chem-angew]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{main.bib}

\begindocument

\printbibliography

\enddocument
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2):

Normally, `biblatex` does not abbreviate journals at all, it will just output what is in the `.bib` file. So you'll probably have to add the missing dots in the source.

As far as the superscripts go, use `\autocite` to obtain superscript citations with this style.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=chem-angew]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem [1]]